# Android Get Image.png from JSON

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON that contains strings and image.png objects.

I can get the string the usual way, but how do I get the Images? All tutorials I found use jsons with specific image URLs instead of the png. Look at the JSON and you will understand it:

```
{
"draw": 0,
"recordsTotal": 8,
"recordsFiltered": 8,
"data": [{
    "start_date": "2017-03-08 17:45:00",
    "competition_name": "Primera Divisi\u00f3n",
    "competition_logo": "laliga.png",
    "home_team": "Deportivo La Coru\u00f1a",
    "home_team_logo": "deportivo-la-coruna-2018.png",
    "home_team_slug": "deportivo-la-coruna-640",
    "event_status": "",
    "away_team": "Real Betis",
    "away_team_logo": "real-betis-2025.png",
    "away_team_slug": "real-betis-639",
    "event_id": "3404",
    "game_minute": ""
},
```

My code has the usual format to get json objects from array.

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String start_date= jsonPart.getString("start_date");
```

I want the home_team_logo and away_team_logo images to put on a ImageView.

Comment: The JSON does not contain "image.png" objects, it contains strings, with the content "image.png". You can get these like any other string

Comment: Yeah. I changed the question cause I didn't expressed myself clear. Thanks.

Comment: you need image url, once you have the url then use `Glide` to display image on image view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the path in which those images are, you can just download the images in asynchronous manner, like so:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public static class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadBitmap(params[0], params[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.potch_app_logo_icon);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
            }
        }
    }
}
private static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url, String localPath) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            return null;
        }
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(localPath));
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
String away_tema_logo_image_name = jsonPart.getString("away_team_logo");
new ImageDownloaderTask(yourImageView).execute(yourUrl, yourLocalPath);
```

This will save the image to local storage on device, so you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: use Glide for images.

Comment: Fantastic, will try mate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you write above, you can get the PNG files name just like this:

```
String start_date= jsonPart.getString("home_team_logo");
```

May be the problem is you want show the  picture in  the view, I think first you want add the URL prefix where from you load the JSON result, and then pass the URL to Glide/ImageLoader like framework to show it on the imageView.

Comment: I edited the question. Yeah, I want to put the images in imageviews. So, I will need their URLs and do what you said?

Comment: What is the finally URL depends on the convention you client App with the server side. For instance, if your json from `http://myserver.com/first.json`, and your picture store in the same server and same directory, then the final URL will be `http://myserver.com/deportivo-la-coruna-2018.png`